# How to use truststore file & password to let KafkaConsumer get topics content in python?

Tags: python, ssl, kafka-consumer-api, truststore

I have been provided truststore file(.jks) & password.

I'm using below code to get messages from kafka topic:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('Topicname',security_protocol = 'SSL', bootstrap['x.com:9092'])
from message in consumer:
   print(message)
```

Above code is printing below error:

```
SSLCertVerificationError: certificate verify failed
```

I know i have not used the truststore file & password.. but unable to figure how to use these information to make above code working.

Basically, i need the python code snippet to use the file.

I would appreciate if anybody can help me.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Lalit, will try & thanks for taking time to answer

Comment: No worries Sir. Happy to help. :) Please do let me know if it works or not.

Comment: it was giving this error: alias does not exist but CARoot.pem was created. 
I included it in the ssl_cafile & when ran the def.. 
i'm getting this error: SSLError:[X509] no certifcate or crl found (_ssl.c:4032).
Can you suggest any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: It could be 2 reasons - the CA certificate might be present with a different alias. Could you try 2 things? First - Check all the certificates in trust store and see if you can find the correct alias? Second - Check the keystore as well because the CA certificate needs to be embedded in keystore as well - then check if the same root certificate is available in the trust store? It just seems like we're referencing the wrong alias here.

Comment: Yes lalit.. i was able to get valid alias using this command 'keytool -list -keystore xyz.jks' but now on running kafkaconsumer def stuck at below issue:
SSLCertVerificationError: SSL: Certificate_verify_failed: unable to get local issuer certifcate (_ssl.c:1051)

Comment: Okay. So, using the valid alias - did you manage to get the CA certificate out? and embed the path in your code?

Comment: Yeah done that.. but stuck at pem error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217302/discussion-between-lalit-and-naseer).

Answer (score 1):

This error can come up if you've got a certificate but the certificate authority is not included in the default CA list.

So, you could embed the root CA certificate by including it in your code. Try the following steps:

1. Extract the root certificate from the Kafka trust store by using the below command:

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -alias CARoot -keystore <TRUST-STORE-PATH> -rfc -file CARoot.pem
   ```
2. Then in your consumer code, you'll need to add the following configuration parameters:

   ```
   from kafka import KafkaConsumer  

   consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='<SERVER-LIST-WITH-PORTS>',
   security_protocol='SSL',
   ssl_check_hostname=True,
   ssl_cafile='<PATH-TO-CARoot.pem>',
   ...
   )
   ```
3. You might also want to verify the ports for SSL communication in `listeners` as it is generally 9093 for SSL instead of 9092.

Hope this helps.